# combining DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms

typically when I have a timepicker and a datePicker on a winform
I combine the two into one date object by using the new DateTime (y,m,d,h,mi,s) constructor.
this seems kind of long winded, and I was wondering what approach others are using if faced with this  situation.

```
DateTime date = 
new DateTime(DatePicker.Value.Year, DatePicker.Value.Month,  DatePicker.Value.Day, 
             TimePicker.Value.Hour, TimePicker.Value.Minute, TimePicker.Value.Second);
```

[image]

looks like it was just a simple.

```
DateTime date  = DatePicker.Value.Date.Add(TimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay);
```

I didn't realize

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hope you have used DateTimePicker for selecting Date and Time. in this case you can combine date and time like

```
DateTime date = DatePicker.Value.Date + TimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) ?

Comment: that's what the question is about

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code helpful:-

```
        int rex01=  t21.Date.Value.Year;                      
        int rex02 = t21.Date.Value.Month;        
        int rex03 = t21.Date.Value.Day;            
        int rex04 = t22.Time.Hours;           
        int rex05 = t22.Time.Minutes;        
        int rex06 = t22.Time.Seconds;                
        DateTime T02 = new DateTime(rex01, rex02, rex03, rex04, rex05, rex06);
```

Please note t21 is a DatePicker and t22 is a TimePicker.

Currently used with respect to SQLite and UWP.

Comment: How did this solve the OPs question? How did you find it helpful?

Comment: The above code offers clarity and could form the basis of a Method, but I prefer to use it as it is, in the absence of a DateTimePicker object.